# How to do an 'insert' into a nonzero position in an empty list?

Tags: python, list

How can I insert a value in a nonzero position in an empty list?

Ex:

```
list = []
.
.
.
list.insert(3, 'value')
```

Comment: you can't, the position does not exist

Comment: List cannot have holes. So it's impossible to add entry to non-zero position of an empty list. If you try, it adds as the first element.

Comment: I don't think python lists allow you to have null in an index.

Comment: you can fill the list with None or Zeros first, and later set in position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists cannot have holes, meaning you cannot add elements to a position that does not exist.

If you try adding element at a non-zero position of an empty list, this is what going to happen:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.insert(3, 'value')
>>> lst
['value']
```

The element is added as the first element of list.

One other way to handle the situation is fill `None` to list and add element at required index.

```
>>> lst = [None] * 5
>>> lst.insert(3, 'value')
>>> lst
[None, None, None, 'value', None, None]
```

To better use your way, I would suggest use a dictionary where key is index and value is the element.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[3] = 'value'
>>> d
{3: 'value'}
```